# Android socket networking

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I had this chat program using sockets and ip addresses.
I tried the code and was working perfectly on my android devices connected via wifi to my router.

I've got the client and server codes from here  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

The code gets the ip address assigned by the router to the android device. The problem is how will I be able to communicate an android device connected to the Router A  via wifi to an android device connected to Router B?

Comment: Wether router A and Router B is connected and allow connection between the hosts

Comment: router A and Router B is connected to the internet and not directly connected to each other

Comment: then it is not a easy way to connect to with simple socket connection program. If your creating a simple chat for private use refer portforwarding the Router, if you want make a Chat application for all users then Refer NAT protocal

Comment: can you explain more about the NAT protocol? Do you know any tutorials?

Comment: http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/group__nat__intro.htm google for more details on it.